# how to delete a previous message if we get new message in django channels

Tags: python, django, websocket, redis, django-channels

I want to broadcast the only latest message of Django-channel layer in a specific room. Right now I have created specific room names for specific users. Now I just want to send them only latest message or note, I don't want to show all the previous messages. Right now all the previous message are showing to user side.

```
    # chat/consumers.py
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer

class ProjectConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        parameter = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']["project_key"]
        print("url_parameter ",parameter)
        
        self.room_name = parameter

        # Join room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)

        instance_user = text_data_json['instance_user']
        sender = text_data_json['sender']
        receiver =  text_data_json['receiver']
        message = text_data_json['message']

        object = {
            'sender':sender,
            'receiver':receiver,
            'message':message,
        }
        # Send message to room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_name,
            {
                'type': 'sent', #function name as an event type
                'object': object #function parameters as an event object
            }
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    async def sent(self, event):

        sender = event['object']["sender"]
        receiver = event['object']["receiver"]
        message = event['object']["message"]

        # Send message to WebSocket
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'sender':sender,
            'receiver':receiver,
            'message':message,
        }))
```

Answer (score 0):

Channel_layer broadcasts only the available message, you are probably appending the message to a DOM element in your front-end

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).